# Quickselect algorithm in Swift

Tags: algorithm, swift, swift3

I recently [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350214/k-largest-element-optimization-swift-3-0/40352054#40352054)
 on Stack Overflow about finding the k-largest element in an array, and 
present my implementation of the *Quickselect* algorithm in Swift for review.

This is essentially the iterative version described in
[Wikipedia: Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), only that the
paritioning does not move the pivot element to the front of the second partition.
That saves some swap operations but requires an additional check when updating the lower bound.

The language is Swift 3, compiled with Xcode 8.1.

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {

    public func kSmallest(_ k: Int) -> Element {
        precondition(1 <= k && k <= count, "k must be in the range 1...count")

        var a = self // A mutable copy.
        var low = startIndex
        var high = endIndex

        while high - low > 1 {

            // Choose random pivot element:
            let pivotElement = a[low + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(high - low)))]

            // Partition elements such that:
            //   a[i] <  pivotElement    for low <= i < pivotIndex,
            //   a[i] >= pivotElement    for pivotIndex <= i < high.
            var pivotIndex = low
            while a[pivotIndex] < pivotElement {
                pivotIndex += 1
            }
            for i in pivotIndex+1 ..< high {
                if a[i] < pivotElement {
                    swap(&a[pivotIndex], &a[i])
                    pivotIndex += 1
                }
            }

            if k <= pivotIndex {
                // k-smallest element is in the first partition:
                high = pivotIndex
            } else if k == pivotIndex + 1 {
                // Pivot element is the k-smallest:
                return pivotElement
            } else {
                // k-smallest element is in the second partition
                low = pivotIndex
                if a[low] == pivotElement {
                    low += 1
                }
            }
        }

        // Only single candidate left:
        return a[low]
    }

    public func kLargest(_ k: Int) -> Element {
        return kSmallest(count + 1 - k)
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
let a = [ 9, 7, 6, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 8 ]
for k in 1 ... a.count {
    print(a.kSmallest(k))
}
// 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

let b = [ "b", "a", "c", "h" ]
print(b.kLargest(2))
// "c"
```

Feedback on all aspects of the code is welcome, such as (but not limited to):

- Possible improvements (speed, clarity, swiftyness, ...).
- Naming. In particular: what would be a better name for `kSmallest(_ k: Int)`
  in consideration of the
  [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)?
- The check `if a[low] == pivotElement` looks artificial, but without that
  an infinite loop can occur, e.g. for an array with all elements equal.
  Is there a better solution?

---

*Remark:* To make this code compile with **Swift 4** (or later), just replace the line

```
swap(&a[pivotIndex], &a[i])
```

with

```
a.swapAt(pivotIndex, i)
```

Comment: Don't you need to manipulate `k` before _iterating the 2nd partition_? (See wikipedia talk page.)

Comment: @greybeard: No, all indices (low, high, pivotIndex) always refer to the original array indices.  I am fairly sure that the method works correctly. Of course I may have overlooked a special case, but I tested it with many random and constructed arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by updating this line to Swift 4.2 :

```
let pivotElement = a[Int.random(in: low..<high)]
```

In my tests, `Int.random(in:)` is way faster than `Int(arc4random_uniform)`, and the comparisons won't take that into consideration.

---

> ### Efficiency

### 1st improvement

There is a small improvement to this algorithm, but it still gives a performance gain by rearranging the conditions from the most probable to the least, in order to take advantage of shortcut execution:

```
if k <= pivotIndex {
    // k-smallest element is in the first partition:
    high = pivotIndex
} else if k > pivotIndex + 1 {
    // k-smallest element is in the second partition
    low = pivotIndex
    if a[low] == pivotElement {
        low += 1
    }
} else {
    // Pivot element is the k-smallest:
    return pivotElement
}
```

The first two conditions are equiprobable. The least probable case is left for last.

**Benchmarks**

The benchmarking code is the following:

```
let a = Array(1...10_000).shuffled()

var timings: [Double] = []
for k in 1 ... a.count {
    let start = mach_absolute_time()
    _ = a.kSmallest(k)
    let end = mach_absolute_time()
    timings.append(Double(end - start)/Double(1e3))
}
let average: Double = timings.reduce(0, +) / Double(timings.count)
print(average, "us")

var timings2: [Double] = []
for k in 1 ... a.count {
    let start = mach_absolute_time()
    _ = a.kSmallest2(k)
    let end = mach_absolute_time()
    timings2.append(Double(end - start)/Double(1e3))
}
let average2: Double = timings2.reduce(0, +) / Double(timings2.count)
print(average2, "us")
```

It prints the average time for looking up one k*th* smallest element.

`kSmallest` is the original, `kSmallest2` is the new one. They both operate on the same array `a` to ensure fairness.

`kSmallest2` is up to `7μs` faster per lookup. The fluctuation is due to the randomness of the arrangement of the elements of the array. Which translates into up to ~`70ms` execution time gain for a 10.000-element array:

```
kSmallest    1.215636265 s (total time)
kSmallest2   1.138085315 s (total time)
```

In the worst case, in my tests, `kSmallest2` may rarely be `2μs` slower per lookup, and it is to be blamed on the randomness of choosing a pivot. Comparisons should probabilistically favor the second version.

---

### 2nd improvement

The following improvement concerns arrays with duplicates, and avoids unnecessary loops:

```
while a[low] == pivotElement, k - low > 1 {
    low += 1
}
```

Instead of hopping by one index alone:

```
if a[low] == pivotElement {
    low += 1
}
```

**Benchmarks**

The following code was used:

```
//As suggested by Tim Vermeulen
let a = (0..<100).flatMap { Array(repeating: $0, count: Int.random(in: 10..<30)) }
    .shuffled()

var timings1: [Double] = []
for k in 1 ... a.count {
    let start = mach_absolute_time()
    _ = a.kSmallest(k)
    let end = mach_absolute_time()
    timings1.append(Double(end - start)/Double(1e6))
}
let average1: Double = timings1.reduce(0, +) / Double(timings1.count)
print("kSmallest", average1, "ms")

var timings2: [Double] = []
for k in 1 ... a.count {
    let start = mach_absolute_time()
    _ = a.kSmallest2(k)
    let end = mach_absolute_time()
    timings2.append(Double(end - start)/Double(1e6))
}
let average2: Double = timings2.reduce(0, +) / Double(timings2.count)
print("kSmallest2", average2, "ms")


var timings3: [Double] = []
for k in 1 ... a.count {
    let start = mach_absolute_time()
    _ = a.kSmallest3(k)
    let end = mach_absolute_time()
    timings3.append(Double(end - start)/Double(1e6))
}
let average3: Double = timings3.reduce(0, +) / Double(timings3.count)
print("kSmallest3", average3, "ms")
```

`kSmallest3` has both the **1st** and **2nd** improvements.

Here are the results:

```
kSmallest  0.0272 ms
kSmallest2 0.0267 ms
kSmallest3 0.0236 ms
```

In an array with a high number of duplicates, the original code is now ~**`13%`** faster by implementing both improvements. That percentage will grow with the richness in duplicates, and a higher array count. If the array has unique elements, `kSmallest2` is naturally the fastest since it'll be avoiding unnecessary checks.

---

### 3rd improvement (a  fix?)

There are unnecessary loops where the the random index is that of a pivot element which is already in *its rightful* place/order. These elements aren't swapped by the code, since they are already well-placed. These elements are the ones that fall in the case of `k > pivotIndex + 1` and the `low` index is equal to `pivotIndex`. An endless loop may occur if `Int.random(in: low..<high)` always returns `low + 1`.

The following code prevents such an (*admittedly unlikely*) endless loop:

```
var orderedLows: Set<Int> = []  //This will contain the indexes of elements that are already well ordered
while high - low > 1 {
    // Choose random pivot element:
    var randomIndex: Int
    repeat {
        randomIndex = Int.random(in: low..<high)
    } while orderedLows.contains(randomIndex) &&
    !orderedLows.isSuperset(of: Array<Int>(low..<high))

    let pivotElement = a[randomIndex]

    ...

    } else if k > pivotIndex + 1 {
        // k-smallest element is in the second partition
        if low == pivotIndex
        {
            orderedLows.insert(randomIndex)
        }
        low = pivotIndex
        while a[low] == pivotElement, k - low > 1 {
            low += 1
        }
    }
```

**Benchmarks**

The following array was operated on with the same benchmarking code as in the second improvment:

```
let a = (0..<100).flatMap { Array(repeating: $0, count: Int.random(in: 10..<30)) }
    .shuffled()
```

And here are the results:

```
kSmallest  0.0662 ms
kSmallest2 0.0639 ms
kSmallest4 0.0575 ms
```

`kSmallest4` being the version with all three improvements, and it is faster than all previous versions. The `a` array was purposefully chosen to be rich in duplicates to heighten the possibilty of elements that are already in the correct order. If not, `kSmallest4` doesn't show any flagrant improvement.

---

> ### Naming

1) `pivotIndex` is confusing, one would expect it t be the index of `pivotElement`, but it's not.

2) `a` isn't very descriptive. Its name neither conveys its mutability nor that it is a copy of the initial array.

3) Such an algorithm, née [`FIND`](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397505004081), is commonly known as `quickSelect` (more names could be found [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quickselect_algorithm#C.2B.2B)). Personally,  I would prefer `nthSmallest(_ n: Int)`, for the following reasons:

- `n` instead of `k` since the latter is usually used in constant naming
- `nth` instead of `n` denotes ordinality
- Since the comparison predicate isn't provided, `nthSmallest(_ n: Int)` would be preferable to `nthElement(_ n: Int)` since it means that we'll be comparing elements in an ascending order.

---

> ### Readability/Alternative approach

If readability and conciseness are paramount, here is an alternative that uses the `partition(by:)` method applied to the array slice `mutableArrayCopy[low..<high]` :

```
public func nthSmallest(_ n: Int) -> Element {
    precondition(count > 0, "No elements to choose from")
    precondition(1 <= n && n <= count, "n must be in the range 1...count")

    var low = startIndex
    var high = endIndex
    var mutableArrayCopy = self

    while high - low > 1 {
        let randomIndex = Int.random(in: low..<high)
        let randomElement = mutableArrayCopy[randomIndex]
        //pivot will be the index returned by partition
        let pivot = mutableArrayCopy[low..<high].partition { $0 >= randomElement }
        if n < pivot + 1 {
            high = pivot
        } else if n > pivot + 1 {
            low = pivot
            //Avoids infinite loops when an array has duplicates
            while mutableArrayCopy[low] == randomElement, n - low > 1 {
                low += 1
            }
        } else {
            return randomElement
        }
    }
    // Only single candidate left:
    return mutableArrayCopy[low]
}
```

In my tests, the more duplicates in the array, the more this version gets on a par (if not better) with the original code, but a bit slower when the array has unique elements.

Here are some tests:

```
[1, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 5, 6, 9, 10].nthSmallest(6)          //6

[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 20, 30, 20, 10].nthSmallest(4) //20

["a", "a", "a", "a", "a"].nthSmallest(3)                //"a"
```

A recursive rewrite of the original code seems more readable. But at the cost of execution time, since each time the function is called, a mutable copy of the array will be created.

Comment: There is a fourth idea: if two elements are equal and are already in their right order (belong to `orderedLows`), and `k` is between their indices, return one of the two elements. This was not included in the answer since it is a special case of a special case...

Comment: The `a[low] == pivotElement` check is somewhat equivalent to an iteration in the outer loop where the swapping condition is `a[i] == pivotElement` instead of `a[i] < pivotElement`. In the `nthSmallest`, it could have been avoided by calling partition twice: with `>=` and then `==`. It was not included since it seemed too verbose.

Comment: I suggest using `flatMap` instead of `reduce(into: []) { $0append(contentsOf: ...) }`

Comment: @TimVermeulen Thank you for the suggestion, I initially didn't understand what you meant. It is now included in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of loops in here. I would probably turn at least one of them into a recursive function; actually, refactoring `high` `low` and `pivotIndex` into `let` constants with recursion *should* be faster due to optimizations. (I'm not that good of an FP programmer to mock something up for you quickly).

Otherwise, one suggestion I'd make (just my preference), you have two major loops smooshed next to each other, perhaps another empty line could help readability:

```
            // Partition elements such that:
            //   a[i] <  pivotElement    for low <= i < pivotIndex,
            //   a[i] >= pivotElement    for pivotIndex <= i < high.
            var pivotIndex = low

            while a[pivotIndex] < pivotElement {
                pivotIndex += 1
            }

            for i in pivotIndex+1 ..< high {
                if a[i] < pivotElement {
                    swap(&a[pivotIndex], &a[i])
                    pivotIndex += 1
                }
            }
```

I would definitely try refactoring some of this to FP, then running it through some `measureBlock()s` in Xcode to see if it's faster.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! – I intentionally chose the iterative version in order to avoid that arrays/slices (which are values in Swift) are passed down and then *copied* when mutated. I am not sure if a recursive version would really be faster, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @MartinR from the limited testing I've done, `let` tends to be significantly faster when passing in values (especially ones that are in-scope such as with recursion). `high` and `low` are both out of scope. However, I think keeping `a` as a var would be a good idea, since swift doesn't have persistent collections (to my knowledge).

Also, from what I've heard "copying" data doesn't actually happen (value) until the data has mutated (they share the same memory space)-- thus, it is essentially a reference. All of those calls to mutate `pivotIndex + 1`should be sped up with `let` and recursion.

Comment: I hope my info isn't wrong xD I'm certainly still learning... :)

Comment: It is correct that arrays (and array slices) are copy-on-write. But here the function *does* mutate the array (slice), which means that additional copies would be made in the nested calls.

Comment: I am sorry, but in its present form (*"I would probably turn at least one of them into a recursive function"*, *"I would definitely try refactoring some of this to FP"*) this answer is too vague to award the bounty.

Comment: @MartinR well its not the first time we have disagreed on something :) This is pretty much the definition  of a program that yearns to be functional, but it may not be faster in swift. regardless im the only one that bothered to review your code. I didnt do it for the bounty, just to help spread the word to those that arent familiar with FP and recursion. /thumbsup I also offered more than just the recursion stateme ts, but its not a big to me